# Where can I find the "Visual Studio Package" Template for Visual Studio project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, plugins

I'm trying to create a plugin (tool window) for Visual Studio 2010, and am following the directives inn MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165051(v=vs.110)

In step #3:
3. In the *Templates* pane click *Visual Studio Package*.

However, in my visual studio I don't see that template (i only see *Visual Studio Add In*)
Why is it missing? Where can I find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your [VS 2010 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2680) is not installed (or it is broken and requires re-installing).

As soon as the SDK is installed, the templates will appear in `[ProgramFiles]\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\` and will be ready to use.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd885119.aspx) page for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running Visual Studio 2010 with the following switches?

```
- devenv /resetskippkgs
- devenv /setup
- devenv /resetttings
- devenv /installvstemplates
```