# "VSPackage" template missing VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have to create an add-in for visual studio 2015. I read at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80493a3w.aspx that "add-in" templates are deprecated from 2013 and "visual studio packages" should be created instead so I tried searching for Visual studio package templates but cannot find them.

I tried the solutions given here [Where can I find the "Visual Studio Package" Template for Visual Studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594167/where-can-i-find-the-visual-studio-package-template-for-visual-studio-project)

But still can't find it. I have the "VSix" template add additional extensibility such as a "VSPackage" but there is no template for a VSPackage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to install the VS 2015 SDK

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn916149.aspx

Comment: It's an optional feature under _Common Tools_ called *Visual Studio Extensibility Tools*. For a fresh install, use "Custom" rather than "Typical" install to select it. Otherwise, you can go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features, select VS 2015, hit "Change" and then "Modify". Then you add it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but the Modify option did not give me the expected options so resorted to downloading the SDK. I +1's you anyway because I agree the docs suggest your method.